# align text to centre in menu li

Tags: html, css

i've created a menu with sub menu in it. for each li i used padding to specify width and align text in the centre in li as suggested by my colleague here is the fiddle created jsfiddle.net/p7Nsf/4/

but i had to divide the each li elements upon 980px so that it will fill 980px so i used width on li items my question is how do i align text to middle of the li element in main menu and sub menu and my sub menu hieght and width has changed itself. here is the updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/p7Nsf/5/

Comment: Vertically center or horizontally center? Also, post your HTML/CSS here please..

Comment: i've put the fiddle as there are two codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `line-height`.

[**Updated jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7Nsf/8/)

**I added:**

```
.menu ul li a {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

**Updated CSS:**

```
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 121px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To fix the dropdown issues, I added:

```
.menu ul ul li a {
    height: 35px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

I specified a width, set `text-align:left`, and added padding.

Comment: line height works but Could you please hover on "admissions" and are you able to see "download application" form menu collapses

Comment: i see that but all the li items in sub menu moves towards right. is it?

Comment: yeah it fine now. what changes have you made?